# Is the Japanese version of Transformers G1 just a dub in a different language, or does it contain different animations/episodes?

Tags: transformers

In the '80s some animations were released both in Japan and the United States but, depending on which one, they could have additional episodes or movies created for one of the countries, such as *Voltron*, which was two different series in Japan, but it had created an episode (or movie, not sure) for the U.S. which featured both.

How does this work for *Transformers*?

**Is the Japanese version of *Transformers G1* just a dub of *Transformers* in a different language, or does it contain different animations and/or episodes?**

Comment: The Japanese wikipedia page for the series claims the Japanese release trimmed each episode down to 25 minutes, which meant cutting some material, but doesn't mention any substantial changes for the first 95 episodes (then the three part miniseries that made season 4 was replaced by 109 Japanese exclusive episodes over three series).

Comment: @Showsni That sounds like an answer and not a commentary to me. So after season 3 there are a lot of new episodes